Misma imagen en diferentes ventanas, Python, Tkinter, "image "pyimage2" doesn't exist"
Tengo el siguiente problema:
Estoy trabajando Tkinter (de Python) y quiero crear simultáneamente dos ventanas que tengan un botón cada una, y dichos botones tengan la misma imagen. Luego podré variar el resto del contenido de la ventana, pero por ahora me es imposible hacer lo que quiero.
Me arroja: _tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist
Que, según he probado, pasa cuando se quiere utilizar imágenes en más de una ventana.
Pareciera que ImageTk.PhotoImage tiene una especie de buffer que no se como vaciar; ya he probado destruyendo o vaciando la variable relacionada y no funciona...
Por otra parte, ya se que hay dudas muy similares a esta... Las he revisado y hasta ahora no hay una respuesta concreta o general para este problema.
Agradeciéndoles de antemano, aquí el código:
import tkinter as tk
import PIL
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk

ventana1 = tk.Tk()
etiqueta1 = tk.Label(ventana1)

ventana2 = tk.Tk()
etiqueta2 = tk.Label(ventana2)

imagen_pil = Image.open("Imagen.JPEG")
imagen_redimencionada = imagen_pil.resize((100, 125))
imagen_rotada = imagen_pil.rotate(45)
imagen_tk1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imagen_redimencionada)
imagen_tk2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imagen_redimencionada)

boton2 = tk.Button(ventana2, image=imagen_tk2)
boton2.pack()

boton1 = tk.Button(ventana1, image=imagen_tk1)
boton1.pack()

ventana2.mainloop()
ventana1.mainloop()


El error no se debe a PIL, es simplmente que como norma general nunca debes tener más de una instancia de tkinter.Tk y mucho menos intentar ejecutar más de un mainloop por proceso.
Tkinter es un wrapper en torno a Tcl/Tk y cada vez que creas una instancia de tkinter.Tk se crea por debajo una nueva instancia de un intérprete Tcl que está aislado del resto. Este sandboxing implica que un widget, variable o imagen creados en uno no es accesible en otro.
Las imágenes pertenecen ambas al intérprete creado al instanciar ventana1, por lo que no puedes usarlas en widgets que pertenecen a ventana2 ya que el intérprete Tcl asociado a la segunda instancia de Tk no puede acceder a las imágenes, de ahí lo de "image "pyimage2" doesn't exist".
Si necesitas multiples ventanas usa tkinter.Toplevel, puedes crear cuantas instancias quieras, mientras se mantine siempre una sola ventana principal y todo ejecutándose bajo el mismo mainloop.
En tu caso puedes hacer que una ventana sea la ventana principal y la otra sea Toplevel:
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


ventana1 = tk.Tk()
etiqueta1 = tk.Label(ventana1)

ventana2 = tk.Toplevel(ventana1)
etiqueta2 = tk.Label(ventana2)

imagen_pil = Image.open("Imagen.JPEG")
imagen_redimencionada = imagen_pil.resize((100, 125))
imagen_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imagen_redimencionada)

boton2 = tk.Button(ventana2, image=imagen_tk)
boton2.pack()

boton1 = tk.Button(ventana1, image=imagen_tk)
boton1.pack()

ventana1.mainloop()

En otros casos puede interesarte ocultar/mostrar (.withdraw()/.deiconify()) la ventana principal y generar dos toplevels.

Gracias, ya pude solucionar. No conocía el funcionamiento de las instancias de Tkinter.
